# Sort JSON data based on nested field

Tags: java, json, sorting, nested

I am trying to solve this problem in Java.
I need to read student data in JSON format from a URL and output it after sorting.
The model is:

```
[
  {
    "name": "string",
    “lecturers”: [
      {
        "name": "string",
        “subject”: "string"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Below is an example of what the JSON data looks like:

```
[
  {
    "name": “Jack”,
    “lecturers”: [
      {
        "name": “Mr.Smith”,
        “subject”: “Music”
      },
      {
        "name": “Mr.Cooper”,
        “subject”: “Physics”
      },
      {
        "name": “Miss.Rae”,
        “subject”: ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": “Dan”,
    “lecturers”: [
      {
        "name": “Miss.Jane”,
        “subject”: “Physics”
      },
      {
        "name": “Mr.Smith”,
        “subject”: “Music”
      },
      {
        "name": “Mr.JJ”
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    “lecturers”: [
      {
        "name": “Mr.Higgs”,
        “subject”: “Art”
      },
      {
        "name": “Mr.Jones”,
        “subject”: “Chemistry”
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The output should be sorted alphabetically as below:

```
Subject A
   Lecturer X
      Student E
   Lecturer Y
Subject B
   Lecturer A
      Student C
      Student D
```

What I have done so far :
As below, read the JSON data using Jackson library's ObjectMapper.

```
public class Student {
    String name;
    List<Lecturer> lecturers;
}
public class Lecturer {
    String name;
    String Subject;
}

List<Student> student =  objectMapper.readValue(new URL(“myUrl”), new TypeReference<List<Student>>(){});
```

How do I go about sorting ? Should I use Java comparator. Not sure how to sort based a field from a list of nested objects. Or should I store the JSON data differently and try to sort ?
Also, as you can see from the example, null values should be handled.

Comment: You could use a numeric comparing function after validating the strings for periods/spaces for title then grabbing the first character where the name starts. If you create the function yourself, it would be little more than a maximum function, where you might conditionally check to see if the two characters at an index are the same and then proceed to finding the maximum value of the next index if they are.